# How to generate multiple ulr in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Here is my trying code, I am trying to generate string to multiple URLs

```js
var customfield_13731 = "one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four"
let chunks = customfield_13731.split(",");
let res = [];
let output = [];
while (chunks.length) {
    let [id, name, key, test] = chunks.splice(0, 4);
    output.push({ id, name, key, test });
}

output.map((item) => {
    let url = `https://test.io/639422/${item.id}/${item.name}/${item.key}/${item.test}`;
    console.log(url)
    document.getElementById("URL").innerHTML = url;
    document.getElementById("URL").setAttribute("href", url);
});
```

when I am getting console.log(URL), I get multiple URL links, but I need to display a browser by dom. I can not display multiple URL in UI

My expected output would be :

```
https://test.io/639422/one/two/three/four
https://test.io/639422/one/two/three/four
```

Comment: A single link can only point to a single url at the same time. You are changing the url of the same link over and over again.

Comment: I want to generate every 4 string is a link , if 100 string are appeared , then it generate 25 url . For example, If my string 1,2,3,4 , then the url would be https://test.io/639422/1/2/3/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append it by using `+=` and not `=` in your `innerHTML` assignment.

Also:

- Use `forEach` not `map` if you don't change the array
- You can do the href and text adding in one step, by simply appending an `a` tag

```js
var customfield_13731 = "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight"
let chunks = customfield_13731.split(",");
let res = [];
let output = [];
while (chunks.length) {
    let [id, name, key, test] = chunks.splice(0, 4);
    output.push({ id, name, key, test });
}

output.forEach((item) => {
    let url = `https://test.io/639422/${item.id}/${item.name}/${item.key}/${item.test}`;

    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML
            += `<a href="${url}">${url}</a><br>`; // append not replace!
});
```

```html
<div id="url"></div>
```

**Edit** (Thank you @Thomas)

A better way would be to concat the strings before adding them to the DOM, opposed to adding them one after the other. This would be a way to do this:

```js
var customfield_13731 = "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight"
let chunks = customfield_13731.split(",");
let res = [];
let output = [];
while (chunks.length) {
    let [id, name, key, test] = chunks.splice(0, 4);
    output.push({ id, name, key, test });
}

const urlParts = output.map((item) => {
    let url = `https://test.io/639422/${item.id}/${item.name}/${item.key}/${item.test}`;

    return `<a href="${url}">${url}</a><br>`;
}).join('');

document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = urlParts;
```

```html
<div id="url"></div>
```

Comment: No! Don't! `innerHTML += ` is bad. Really really bad. Not only is it bad for performance *(especially in a loop)*, but if you had added event-listener, or hold a reference to one of the existing elements in `#url` you would have just broken your code. Concat the strings first and do a single `innerHTML = entireMarkup;`

Comment: Yeah, if you want to preserve event listeners, you need to use DOM functions. Seeing that this isn't the case here, this was the easiest fix in my view. Maybe not the best

Comment: Even if you only add 10 elements. The code will have parsed markup 10 times, created 55 DOM-Nodes and thrown away 45 of them. At 100 items we'Re at ~5000 unnecessary nodes and for 200 at ~20K. That's a lot of garbage produced for "the easiest fix in my view". And especially inexperienced users, the kind that reads this kind of answers, will not be aware of that.

Comment: It still is the easiest fix for the given problem in my opinion. Either way, I have added your suggestion as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create multiple anchor elements

```js
var customfield_13731 = "one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four"
let chunks = customfield_13731.split(",");
let res = [];
let output = [];
while (chunks.length) {
    let [id, name, key, test] = chunks.splice(0, 4);
    output.push({ id, name, key, test });
}

output.map((item) => {
    let url = `https://test.io/639422/${item.id}/${item.name}/${item.key}/${item.test}`;
    console.log(url)
    
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = url;
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    
    document.getElementById("URL").appendChild(a);
});
```

```css
a { display: block }
```

```html
<div id="URL"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version.

I have added a utility function, because it's not the first time I had to turn a long list into rows/pages/groups, and DRY.

```js
// DRY, not the first time I needed this.
const toGroupsOf = (n, array) => Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(array.length/n)|0 }, (_,i) => array.slice(n*i, n*i+n));

var customfield_13731 = "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight";

document.getElementById("URL").innerHTML = toGroupsOf(4, customfield_13731.split(","))
  .map(([id,name,key,test]) => {
    let url = `https://test.io/639422/${id}/${name}/${key}/${test}`;
    return `<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`;
  })
  .join("\n");
```

```css
a { display: block }
```

```html
<div id="URL"></div>
```